# MS SQL Server: Select of columns based on values in column and at least 4 values in another column in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table in MS SQL Server like below:

| title | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bigpay | Merk Simon | AL RuT PHU RU |
| payment | Neville Ann | ARG |
| cash 11 | Bravo John | Garry Owen A CD |
| burger | Tomas Per | Lucky Bank |

I need to select only these rows where:

1. in column "title" is phase "pay" or "cash in any configuration
2. In column "name2" there is at least 4 values (4 or more values in that columns)

So, I need result like below:

| title | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bigpay | Merk Simon | AL RuT PHU RU |
| cash 11 | Bravo John | Garry Owen A CD |

bacause only this two rows meet requirements: "pay" or "cash" in title and at least 4 values in column "name2"

Comment: How does "cash 11" meet your conditions?  (Hint:  It doesn't.)

Comment: name2 column value 'Garry Owen' doesn't have 4 tokens.

Comment: yes u a right I changed it and now is Garry Owen A CD so 4 values

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the names in `name2` assuming that one space is the separator:

```
select t.*
from t
where (title like '%pay%' or title like '%cash%') and
      (1 +
       len(name2) - len(replace(name2, ' ', ''))
      ) >= 4;
```

Or, because these are all in one column, you can use `like`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (title like '%pay%' or title like '%cash%') and
      name2 like '% % % %';
```

That is, it has at least three spaces.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c2a17c2a366d59a56ac3d9849eed15e) is a db<>fiddle showing that both work.

Comment: I have error: 'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name. if I use first solution

Comment: and like does not work correctly I have values which have only 2 values

Comment: @gato . . . You should not need the trim anyway.  You should set up a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

***Since SQL Server 2016, Compatibility Level 130 and higher***, the string_split function can be used to separate words using a delimiter. If a space is used for the delimiter, then a where clause filter can eliminate the extra empty spaces (i.o.w. the empty words) returned. Since string_split creates a new row per each word split, the original output can be grouped, and the number of words counted. A having clause can be used to only return counts above a certain number. If we don't care to see the word count column, then a CTE can be used to avoid selecting it.

For example:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (title varchar(20), name1 varchar(20), name2 varchar(100));
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES 
 ('bigpay', 'Merk Simon', 'AL RuT PHU RU')
,('payment', 'Neville Ann' ,'ARG')
,('cash 11', 'Bravo John', 'Garry Owen A CD')
,('burger', 'Tomas Per', 'Lucky Bank');

WITH CTE AS(
SELECT title, name1, name2, COUNT(*) as [words]
  FROM @temp
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(name2, ' ') AS d2
 Where value <> '' --eliminate extra spaces
   AND (title LIKE '%pay%' OR title LIKE '%cash%')
GROUP BY title, name1, name2
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
)
SELECT title, name1, name2 FROM CTE;
```

Produces output:

```
title                name1                name2
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------
bigpay               Merk Simon           AL RuT PHU RU
cash 11              Bravo John           Garry Owen A CD
```